# How to define sets in cplex

Tags: cplex

I am working on enhancing the resilience of power distribution networks and using IBM CPLEX Optimization Studio to model the problem. The power distribution network I am considering is composed of 32 lines. Among these lines, 9 distribution lines have been damaged due to natural disasters, and 3 distribution lines are equipped with remotely controlled switches(RCS). I aim to write constraints that accurately represent the undamaged branches and the branches without remotely controlled switches in the optimization problem. kindly guide me in writing this constraint. the detail about the constraint is given below.

- L_switch - set of branches equipt with remotely controlled switches.
- L_t_damaged - set of branches that are damaged and have not been repaired at time t.
- αij,t - Connection status of the branch (i, j) at time t (1 if the branch is connected, 0 otherwise).
- α0_ij - Binary parameter representing the initial status of the branch (i, j) (1 if the branch is connected, 0 otherwise).

The expression for the constraint is given below.

- αij,t = α0_ij ∀(i, j) ∈ L \ { L_t_damaged ,L_switch }, ∀t ∈ T.

where symbol \ indicates, L_t_damaged and L_switch sets get excluded form set L.
(The constraint means that the undamaged branches without RCS remain in their initial status over all time periods)

I want the constraint to be written in CPLEX.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation or looking at the examples provided with CPLEX?

Comment: yes, I have tried but I am not getting anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sir actually the subset of damaged lines i.e.  L_t_damaged is changing with time because repairing is also going after some time interval. In my problem, I have considered the time of 24 hours. Suppose I have 32 distribution line, 9 lines out of which is damaged initially. In the 3rd hour, one of the lines gets repaired and in the 6th hour another line gets repaired and similarly, in the 9th hour, another line gets repaired, and so on. So, please guide me on how to write the code in CPLEX for the line damage subset whose element and number change with time.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you can write

```
{int} L=asSet(1..32);
{int} L_t_damaged=asSet(1..9);
{int} L_switch=asSet(10..12);

range T=1..3;

int alpha0[l1 in L][l2 in L]=rand(1); // random as a start
dvar boolean alpha[L][L][T];

subject to
{
  
  //  undamaged branches without RCS remain in their initial
  // status over all time periods
  forall(t in T)
    forall(i,j in L diff (L_t_damaged union L_switch))
      alpha[i][j][t]==alpha0[i][j];
}
```